# Node/Git Bash, distorted file path when starting server. Bug or user error?

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, node-modules, git-bash, nodemon

I'm following along with an example mean stack project. Node/nodemon is experiencing issues in git bash where it produces a throw error when I try to start the server.

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Emma\desktop\trainingapprc\app.js'
```

The main directory is called trainingapp, and below it should be src\app.js. Nodemon is leaving out a "\s" between the root directory and src, causing the error. When I run the server with just node, it forgets the src folder completely:

```
    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Emma\desktop\trainingapp\app.js'
```

I pulled the example project from github and it does not have this error, even though the directory tree is exactly the same except for the directory name.

I'm new to coding so I'm not sure how to proceed. Is this a bug or user error?

Comment: Can you go to this file path and try to start the server from there..`nodemon app.js`

Comment: @prabhatmishra Yes if I'm inside src I can start the server, however the only thing that renders is "Cannot get /". Javascript console produces a 404 error:  

        Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)  
 

So I think the corrupted file path is affecting other parts of my code?

Comment: actually can't figure it out without seeing the code..

Comment: @prabhatmishra is a github link ok? https://github.com/elryan02/trainingapp.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Comment out Lines In app.js:

```
var router = require('./api');   
app.use('/api', router);
```

2.place a `.` in the code `../public` :

```
app.use('/', express.static('../public'));
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the routing issue I was having. Nodemon is still acting abnormally but at least I can keep working now. Thank you for your help!